# HTTP: guidelines for common User-Agent: headers?

Tags: http, header, user-agent

I'm sure there's no official standard, but are there some guidelines for identifying and classifying browsers based on the User-Agent string they send?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [RFC 2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.43), here is the convention used by client to send their User-Agent.

```
User-Agent = "User-Agent" ":" 1*( product | comment )
```

Example:

```
User-Agent: CERN-LineMode/2.15 libwww/2.17b3
```

The header *should* contains a [product token](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html#sec3.8), and additional informations about version, used library by the client, etc.

But as you may know, User-Agent can totally be faked, so you can't really rely on it.

[user-agents.org](http://www.user-agents.org/) is a searchable database of user-agents